# JQuery select the next element

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use JQuery to select the next element in a set of elements with the same class.

Here is the HTML setup:

```
<div class="sameClass selected">
  <p>Text in here</p>
</div>
<div class="differentClass">
  <p>Text in here
</div>
<div class="sameClass">
  <p>Text in here</p>
</div>
```

When I have the first div with the class "sameClass" I would like to remove the "selected" class from the top div and apply it to the next div with the class "sameClass" so the results are like so:

```
<div class="sameClass">
  <p>Text in here</p>
</div>
<div class="differentClass">
  <p>Text in here
</div>
<div class="sameClass selected">
  <p>Text in here</p>
</div>
```

I hope you get what I mean :)

UPDATE:

I have found that this one works the best.

```
$(".sameClass.selected").nextAll(".sameClass:first").andSelf().toggleClass("selected")
```

I have encountered one bug with it how ever, if the HTML is like so:

```
<p>
  <div class="sameClass">
    <p>Text in here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="differentClass">
    <p>Text in here
  </div>
  <div class="sameClass  selected">
    <p>Text in here</p>
  </div>
</p>
<p>
  <div class="sameClass">
    <p>Text in here</p>
  </div>
</p>
```

It will not select the "sameClass" which is in the second P block.  Any idea why this is happening?

Eef

Comment: the solution you've chosen (my code) doesn't work because in your original example you did not mention that the divs will be spanned across multiple <P> tags, they have to be on the same level for it to work. And Please put your comments under the post of the specific solution you've chosen.

Comment: Ah ok - Do you have any pointers on how to get this working if the divs are spanned across multiple elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an elegant solution:

```
$(".sameClass.selected")
 .nextAll(".sameClass:first").andSelf()
 .toggleClass("selected")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
$('.sameClass').each(function() {
  if(setNextAsSelected) {
      this.addClass('selected');
      return;
  }
  if (this.attr('class').contains('selected')) { 
      setNextAsSelected = true;
      this.removeClass('selected'); 
  }
});
```

or something (Mostly pseudocoded).

Comment: $('.sameClass').each(function() {
    if (this.attr('class').contains('selected')) 
    { 
      setNextAsSelected = true 
      this.removeClass('selected');
    }
    if(setNextAsSelected)
    {
       this.addClass('selected');
       setNextAsSelected =false;
    }
});

Comment: thanks, i kinda wrote it in a rush, and have been slowly editting it ;p

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var sel = $('.selected');
sel.removeClass('selected');
var ofSameClass = sel.siblings('.'+sel.attr('class'));
ofSameClass.eq(0).addClass('selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( '.sameClass' ).each ( function () {
  var jThis = $( this );
  if ( jThis.hasClass ( 'selected' ) ) {
    jThis.removeClass ( 'selected' );
    jThis.nextAll ( '.sameClass' ).each ( function () {
      $( this ).addClass ( 'selected' );
      return false;
    } );

    return false;
  }
} );
```

Comment: this will add .selected to next all .sameClass divs; which is not what he meant

Comment: it will not. notice the first "return false;" :)

Answer (score 0):

You dont make it clear if your always going forward to find the 'next' div.
So either use .nextAll or .siblings.eq(0) depends if you going both left and right.

```
var $el = $('div.selected');
$el.removeClass('selected');
   .nextAll('.' + $el.attr('class') ).eq(0)
   .addClass('selected');
```

Also do not forget to use tagname prefix in the selector rather than a pure class based selector $('div.class') 99% of the time better than $('.class')

P.S instead of nextAll you could use ben almans nextUntil plugin available @ http://github.com/cowboy/jquery-misc

Answer (score 0):

Modification to Jimmeh's reply

```
var setNextAsSelected = false;
$('.sameClass').each(function() {
    if (this.hasClass('selected')) 
    { 
      setNextAsSelected = true 
      this.removeClass('selected');
    }
    if(setNextAsSelected)
    {
       this.addClass('selected');
       setNextAsSelected =false;
    }
});
```

Comment: as suggested in my comments, the if statements are the wrong way round, but otherwise seems fine.

Comment: you need to set flag when current item has .selected before removing. For the next .sameClass item flag==true means add .selected to current.

Comment: yea, but this will basically find the selected item, then remove the selected, then re add it to the same item. You could use and else if, but currently, this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and I think it does what you want:

```
var s='selected';
var c='.sameClass';
$($(c+'.'+s).removeClass(s).nextAll(c)[0]).addClass(s)
// s and c added for brevity, probably use this expanded in source code.
```

It does not work if the last `.sameClass` element was selected, but then, neither do the other answers so far.

Answer (score -1):

Try with this:

```
$('.sameClass.selected')
    .removeClass('selected')
    .nextAll('.sameClass:eq(0)')
       .addClass('selected')'
```

Comment: .prev only ever returns the previous sibling, you need prevAll()

Comment: you're right, i haven't tested this. i've posted it while having morning coffee, it might be that it haven't awaken me enough :)

anyway, i've edited my answer with code that works (and uses nextAll)

Comment: but now it adds selected to all next siblings that have the same class, not just the next one ( .eq(0) )

Comment: again, you're right :)
so in nextAll selector should be '.sameClass:eq(0)'